# Not sure why my JavaScript code is not working?

Tags: javascript

I keep getting an error saying I cant use `==` when comparing to 0 in my `if` statements. What are the errors in my code, because I have looked through it, and I am not sure why my code is not running

```
var table=[];                            // declare table array. 
var fiveTable=[], tenTable=[],squareTable=[];   //declare fiveTable, tenTable, and squareTable array


for(var i =1;i<=10;i++)     //This for loop will populate the table array. 
{
table[i]=i;
}   

for(var i=0; i<101;i++) //This for loop will populate the fiveTable, tenTable, and squareTable array
{


if(i+1<=51)  //Stops populating fiveTable once i reachs 51
{

    fiveTable[i]=5*(i+1);

}

if(i+1<=101)
//Stops populating fiveTable once i reachs 101      
{

    tenTable[i]=10*(i+1);

}

if(i+1<=10)
//Stops populating squareTable once i reachs 10     
{

    squareTable[i]=table[i]*table[i];

}


}

console.log("These are the odd multiples of 5 between 1 and 100"); //Prints a string

for(var i=1;i<=100;i++) 
{
    if(i%2!=0&&i%5==0) //Checks if i is odd and a multiple of 5
{
    console.log(i); //prints all odd multiples of 5
}           
}

console.log("These are the sum of even multiples of 7 between 1 and 100");

for(var i=1;i<=100;i++)
{
if(i%2==0&&i%7==0)  //Checks if i is even and a multiple of 7
{
    console.log(i); //prints all even multiples of 7
}
}
console.log("          **************Problem #5 Curry 
Function***************");
function cylinder_volume(r){ //This is the start of the curried function
return function(h){// returning a function 
return 3.14*r*r*h; // This will the return the value that is desired from 
the function
};
}

var r=5; // initialize r with 5
var h=10;// initialize h with 10
console.log(cylinder_volume(r)(h));//  prints the value of the curried 


console.log("          **************EXTRA**********CREDIT***************");

console.log("These are the even multiples of 5 between 1 and 100"); //Prints a string

for(var i=1;i<=100;i++) 
{
    if(i%2==0&&i%5==0) //Checks if i is even and a multiple of 5
{
    console.log(i); //prints all even multiples of 5
}           
}

console.log("These are the sum of odd multiples of 7 between 1 and 100");

for(var i=1;i<=100;i++)
{
if(i%2!=0&&i%7==0)  //Checks if i is odd and a multiple of 7
{
    console.log(i); //prints all odd multiples of 7
}
}
```

Comment: The "error" is coming from a lint? Or you're just trolling?

Comment: I don't know what lint is i have never used JavaScript before

Comment: Lint is a code analyzer, it notifies you when you're using bad practices. There's no syntax errors in your code (after removing line breaks from some strings/inline comments), [it seems to work](https://jsfiddle.net/84to1txu/) ..?

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help.

Comment: Your code works fine

Comment: Can you tell me what IDE your using? I ran my code on the chrome browser by pushing ctrl+shift+j and it worked, but when I ran it somewhere else I wouldn't run.

Comment: What do you mean when you "ran it elsewhere"?  Be specific, not vague.